# Media Directory in Django

Tags: django

What are MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in django and why do we need to use them?
Can't we directly add images directly into the database by logging in to admin account.

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/ and the section https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development?

Comment: I have seen but was not able to understand

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what it is you don't understand specifically that's not addressed in the official howto?

Comment: I didn't understood that why do we need such a media directory.

Comment: Also I didn't understood the line os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main confusion might be `MEDIA` vs `STATIC`. It's pretty clear in the docs, still:

**STATIC** is basically where you keep your files that are required to run your website properly, say css, js, some jpg/png/img files (say site logo, background, favicon etc).

**MEDIA** is for user uploaded files. Say, a user uploads his/her resume, profile photo etc.

`MEDIA_ROOT`: is the absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.

`MEDIA_URL`: is the URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. E.g.  the `/media/` in `www.example.com/media/somefile.mp4`

`STATIC_ROOT`: is the absolute path to the directory where your static files are placed for deployment.

`STATIC_URL`: URL to use when referring to static files located in STATIC_ROOT. E.g. the `/static/` in `www.example.com/static/mysite.css`

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT